# How to draw a rectangle by start point and end point?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Right now I can draw a rectangle by start point with width and height.

```
context.strokeStyle = "red";
context.beginPath();
context.rect(startX, startY, width, height);
context.stroke();
```

My question can I draw with , startX, startY, EndX, EndY ?

Comment: What you mean? so I can directly use rect(startX, startY, endX, endY) to draw a rectangle on canvas?

Comment: No, of course you can not, because the rect method does not work that way. But you can easily write your own function that takes those values and _calculates_ the necessary values to call rect with.

Comment: You mean like draw 4 lines and put them together ?

Comment: Still not get the point, I am really sorry. Can you show some code?

Comment: Oh come on, `height = endY - startY`. Can you guess the length?

Comment: How do you think the rect method as it is determines the lower right corner of the rectangle to draw? Maybe by _adding_ the width/height to the left/top coordinate …? Could that operation be reversed maybe …?

Comment: Sorry all of you. It is really a simple Math. I really need a coffee right now.

Comment: `context.rect(startX, startY, endX-startX, endY-startY);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope this helps.

```
func rectFromStartAndEnd(_ startPoint:CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint) -> CGRect
{
  var  top, left, bottom, right: CGFloat;
  top = min(startPoint.y, endPoint.y)
  bottom = max(startPoint.y, endPoint.y)

  left = min(startPoint.x, endPoint.x)
  right = max(startPoint.x, endPoint.x)

  let result = CGRect(x: left, y: top, width: right-left, height: bottom-top)
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write your own function to draw the rectangle for you. If you have two points `(x1 , y1)` and `(x2, y2)`, then the width is the difference in x so `x2 - x1` and the height the difference in y so `y2 - y1`.

Using this, your function may be something like:

```
function drawRect(x1, y1, x2, y2){
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
    context.stroke();
}
```

Alternatively, if you would rather not use a function, just do:

```
context.rect(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
```